# Looking for a way to interface a mag-stripe reader Android

Tags: android, serial-port, credit-card

I'm relatively new to android development, but not to programming.  I'd like to be able to use an Android Tablet with a mag-stripe reader, either via bluetooth or USB interface.  Is Android capable of reading the serial input from the gun?  If so, can anyone point me to the libraries I would need to write classes for this input?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876274/android-how-to-read-magnetic-stripecredit-cards-etc-data

Comment: hi andrew got any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Square uses an audio jack mag-stripe reader.  You could use a similar device like this: http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/112.html

Comment: excellent option, thank you.  Now all I have to do is figure out how to interface with it

Comment: Could you accept this answer (if this is the best one of course)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to build your skimming gear would be to use a standard serial usb dongle/chip  (such as one from [ftdi](http://www.ftdichip.com/)) that already has a serial driver for linux. There are a lot of good magnet card readers that talk RS-232, and programming against a serial device is a piece of cake compared to writing a usb-driver without documentation.