# credit card payment process integration in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, credit-card, merchant-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [iOS - Integrating credit card payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762096/ios-integrating-credit-card-payments)

I want to make a application in which the payment is been done one user swap the card in the external card reader([iMag](http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/105.html),[iDynamo](http://www.magtek.com/V2/products/secure-card-reader-authenticators/iDynamo.asp),[Square](https://squareup.com/register#signup)) attached with the device(iphone,ipad etc)

Is there any sdk available or is there any way or sample code which gives some guideline to integrate such hardware with the application.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you got sdk for the same. If yes so please help. if it is paid we will purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- [Android: How to read Magnetic Stripe(credit cards, etc) Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876274/android-how-to-read-magnetic-stripecredit-cards-etc-data)
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4056057?start=0&tstart=0